# How to upload a file in our system to aws using python and boto3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, boto3

i have created an aws account, launched ec2 instance and created buckets in s3. Also i have installed python, boto3 and aws cli. But i'm stuck on connecting python with aws step.

Comment: Are you having trouble with your AWS credentials and boto3? If so, have you looked at this documentation https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/quickstart.html#configuration ?

Comment: For the upload part of this, a simple search for "boto3 s3 upload file" will yield many examples. Here's one example: https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.upload_file

Answer (score 0):

The first and foremost thing that you need to check is whether your EC2 instance has permissions to access the S3 bucket. This can be done in 2 ways:

1. Store the credentials in the EC2 instance (insecure)
2. Assign IAM roles to the EC2 instance that has S3 read and write permissions (secure)

In order to assign a role to your instance, follow [this guide](http://parthicloud.com/how-to-access-s3-bucket-from-application-on-amazon-ec2-without-access-credentials/).

Once your permissions are set up, you can either use the AWS CLI or BOTO3 to access S3 from your EC2 instance.

Answer (score 0):

**1:** If you are asking how to establish a connection for running your AWS-python codes then you must follow these steps on terminal:

- **aws configure** (this ill ask you credentials which you will find in the **.CSV** file that is created initially)
- Provide the credentials and try to run the code
- For ex:
  ***$ aws configure

  AWS Access Key ID [None]: AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE

  AWS Secret Access Key [None]: wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY

  Default region name [None]: us-west-2

  Default output format [None]: json***

**2:** If your question is how you will use the boto3 API calls to run AWS functions then this might help you:
If you are using boto3 SDK then you can make use of low-level clients and higher-level.
**ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')

client = boto3.client('ec2')**
You can follo this link for more detailed info : http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html